# How to add list filter and search field in Wagtail default admin Page

Tags: wagtail

Is there any way to put a search field and list filters in a Page-derived model, without customize a ModelAdmin? I would like to use the default admin page for Page-derived model.

models.py

```
class FolderPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('embedded_video', EmbedBlock(icon='media')),
        ('table', TableBlock()),
    ], null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Corpo da Notícia')

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('body'),
        index.SearchField('title'),
        index.FilterField('live'),
    ]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is a feature in development, you cand see [here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/4524) in order to get a direction about that.